# IE8 + jQuery: Parent DIV fires HOVER event of first child

Tags: jquery, css, html, internet-explorer-8, hover

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/2JUEJ

What happens when I open the page in IE8 is that, whenever the mouse enters a container DIV (class=tableRow), the `hover` event of its first child DIV (class=tile/wideTile/longTile) fires. Works fine in Fx. I have tried using `event.preventDefault();` in the parent's `hover` event, but that doesn't fix it. Any clues?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but if you replace `event.preventDefault()` with `event.stopPropagation()` that might work. `preventDefault()` will just stop the default behaviour of your element, which in your case, has none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combination of `float:left` and `display:table-cell` on the `.tile` class [**is incompatible**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo). Setting `float` automatically sets the display to *block*. Take a look at the computed style in Chrome or Firebug/Firefox.

It might even be the case that floating the table-cell is actually causing the browser to generate [anonymous table objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) which is causing the rendering error in IE8. I guess Chrome/Firefox are interpreting the incompatibility differently.

Removing `display:table-row` causes IE to render the cells slightly better in that the first cell's hover event is no longer triggered when hovering over other row children. However this breaks the intended layout, therefore I recommend using a new approach.

First remove all the `display:table-*` rules since everything is floated (which as I already said sets `display:block`) and since everything is floated, each `table` will need a width, otherwise all the elements will sit horizontal to each other. For example I tried `420px` on the `.table` class.

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7qFH/2/).

Note: Personally I would go one better and remove the floats completely and just use a combination of `display:inline-block;vertical-align:top` and possibly some positioning, since floating generally requires extra rules and/or markup to clear (and I've never liked CSS float!)

Other questions that you might helpful explaining parts of this answer:

- [IE7: How to make TD float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018125/ie7-how-to-make-td-float)
- [float:left; vs display:inline; vs display:inline-block; vs display:table-cell;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell)
- [Floating table cells in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279517/floating-table-cells-in-ie7)

Comment: And your tip not only fixed the issue, but made it look fine in IE7 also. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".title").hide();
    $(".tile, .wideTile, .longTile").hover(function() {
       $("div[class=title]", this).stop().slideDown("fast");
    }, function() {
       $("div[class=title]", this).stop().slideUp("fast");
    });
});
```

try using this script and see if this helps.

Comment: Tried that, still the same. :(

Answer (score 0):

The event is propagated from child to parent. Try event.stopPropagation() in child div hadlers.